# Blazor Loading issue with images and Html Head Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I got strange flickering when coming to my blazor server side application.

For better user experience I implemented a GIF throbber but afterwards the loading is not fluently as you can see yourself:

https://shop6.gastroblitz.de/streetchooser

My goal is that the page should appear completely and in one refresh after the loading throbber is done:

some ideas for performance issues (but don't have an idea to improve with my current knowledge...):

1. _Host.cshtml

   - PreRender "HtmlHeadComponent" in the  area (for generating domain specific title, meta data, etc.)

     ```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <base href="~/" />
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,
                       width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
                       minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,
                       user-scalable=no" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />

     <script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage/protectedBrowserStorage.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/animations.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/simplebar.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/articlePopup.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/accordion.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js">  </script>
     <script src="/js/my.js"></script>
     <script src="_content/Blazor-Analytics/blazor-analytics.js"></script>

     @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<HtmlHeadComponent>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
     </head>
     <body>
     <app>
         @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
     </app>

     <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
     <script>
         Blazor.defaultReconnectionHandler._reconnectCallback = function (d) {
             document.location.reload();
         }
     </script>
     <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/17.4.43/dist/ej2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.syncfusion.com/ej2/17.4.43/dist/ejs.interop.min.js"></script>
     </body>
     </html>
     ```
2. App.razor

   - Here I just start when every data is loaded (see the if statement + many CascadingParameters for handling data changes in sub components)

     ```
     <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
     <Found Context="routeData">
         @if (AppState.StoreData != null &&
          AppState.MultiStoreData != null &&
          AppState.StoreChooserData != null)
         {
             <CascadingValue Value="AppState.StoreData" Name="StoreData">
                 <CascadingValue Value="AppState.MultiStoreData" Name="MultiStoreData">
                     <CascadingValue Value="AppState.StoreChooserData" Name="StoreChooserData">
                         <CascadingValue Value="AppState.BasketData" Name="BasketData">
                             <CascadingValue Value="AppState.CheckoutData" Name="CheckoutData">
                                 <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
                                 <GoogleAnalytics TrackingId="@AppState.StoreData?.StoreContainer?.Store?.GoogleAnalyticsId" />
                             </CascadingValue>
                         </CascadingValue>
                     </CascadingValue>
                 </CascadingValue>
             </CascadingValue>
         }
         else
         {
             <img class="center" src="/img-dev/ajax-loader.gif" />
         }
     </Found>
     <NotFound>
         <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
             <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
         </LayoutView>
     </NotFound>
     ```
3. Last step is the given storechooser page which loads content also just when all data is available

   ```
       @page "/streetchooser"

   @inherits StreetChooserBase
   @if (StoreChooserData != null && MultiStoreData != null)
   {
        <div class="slider" id="home">
           <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme pitch_img">
               @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MultiStoreData.MultiStore.StreetChooserImage1))
               {
                   <div class="item">
                       <img src="img/@StoreData?.StoreContainer?.Store?.Key/@MultiStoreData.MultiStore.StreetChooserImage1" alt="" class="pitch_img" />
                   </div>
               }
               @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MultiStoreData.MultiStore.StreetChooserImage2))
               {
                   <div class="item">
                       <img src="img/@StoreData?.StoreContainer?.Store?.Key/@MultiStoreData.MultiStore.StreetChooserImage2" alt="" class="pitch_img" />
                   </div>
               }
               @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MultiStoreData.MultiStore.StreetChooserImage3))
               {
                   <div class="item">
                       <img src="img/@StoreData?.StoreContainer?.Store?.Key/@MultiStoreData.MultiStore.StreetChooserImage3" alt="" class="pitch_img" />
                   </div>
               }
               @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MultiStoreData.MultiStore.StreetChooserImage4))
               {
                   <div class="item">
                       <img src="img/@StoreData?.StoreContainer?.Store?.Key/@MultiStoreData.MultiStore.StreetChooserImage4" alt="" class="pitch_img" />
                   </div>
               }
               @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MultiStoreData.MultiStore.StreetChooserImage5))
               {
                   <div class="item">
                       <img src="img/@StoreData?.StoreContainer?.Store?.Key/@MultiStoreData.MultiStore.StreetChooserImage5" alt="" class="pitch_img" />
                   </div>
               }
           </div>
           <div class="slider_content ">
               <div class="container">
                   <div class="row ">
                       <div class="col-sm-5">
                           @if (StoreChooserData != null && MultiStoreData != null)
                           {
                               <EditForm Model="@StoreChooserData">
                                   <div class="search-section">
                                       <div class="search-logo">
                                           <img src="img/@StoreData?.StoreContainer?.Store?.Key/@StoreData?.StoreContainer?.Store?.LogoUrl" alt="" />
                                       </div>
                                       <p>Sushi und mehr online bestellen und abholen oder direkt nach Hause liefern lassen.</p>
                                       <div class="row">
                                           <div class="col-sm-6">
                                               <div class="select-location @(StoreChooserData.OrderType == "1" ? "active" : "")"
                                                    @onclick="OrderTypeChangedToDelivery"> Lieferung</div>
                                           </div>
                                           <div class="col-sm-6">
                                               <div class="select-location @(StoreChooserData.OrderType == "2" ? "active" : "")"
                                                    @onclick="OrderTypeChangedToPickup"> Selbstabholer</div>
                                           </div>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="search-rest">
                                           <label>Plz / Ort </label>
                                           <EjsComboBox Value="@StoreChooserData.PostcodeCitySite"
                                                        ModelType="@typeof(Db_DeliveryStreet)"
                                                        Placeholder="Ort eingeben"
                                                        ShowClearButton="true"
                                                        AllowCustom="true"
                                                        AllowFiltering="true"
                                                        FilterType="FilterType.Contains"
                                                        NoRecordsTemplate="<div>Keine Ergebnisse</div>"
                                                        DataSource="@MultiStoreData.DeliveryZones">
                                               <AutoCompleteEvents TValue="string" ValueChange="PostcodeCityChanged"></AutoCompleteEvents>
                                               <ComboBoxFieldSettings GroupBy="Postcode" Value="FullName"></ComboBoxFieldSettings>
                                               <ComboBoxTemplates>
                                                   <GroupTemplate Context="Item">
                                                       <span class="group">@((Item as Db_DeliveryStreet).Postcode)</span>
                                                   </GroupTemplate>
                                                   <ItemTemplate Context="Item">
                                                       <span><span class='name'>@((Item as Db_DeliveryStreet).CitySite)</span><span class='minOrderValue'>@($"ab {(Item as Db_DeliveryStreet).MinOrderValue?.ToString("f2")}€")</span></span>
                                                   </ItemTemplate>
                                               </ComboBoxTemplates>
                                           </EjsComboBox>
                                           <ValidationMessage For="@(() => StoreChooserData.PostcodeCitySite)">
                                           </ValidationMessage>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="search-rest">
                                           <label>Straße / Hausnr. </label>
                                           <EjsComboBox Value="@StoreChooserData.Street"
                                                        ModelType="@typeof(StreetItem)"
                                                        Placeholder="Straße eingeben"
                                                        ShowClearButton="true"
                                                        AllowCustom="true"
                                                        AllowFiltering="true"
                                                        FilterType="FilterType.Contains"
                                                        NoRecordsTemplate="<div>Keine Ergebnisse</div>"
                                                        DataSource="@Streets">
                                               <AutoCompleteEvents TValue="string" ValueChange="StreetChanged"></AutoCompleteEvents>
                                               <ComboBoxFieldSettings Value="Name"></ComboBoxFieldSettings>
                                           </EjsComboBox>
                                           <ValidationMessage For="@(() => StoreChooserData.Street)"></ValidationMessage>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class="search-rest">
                                           <button class="search-send-btn" @onclick="@GoToNext">weiter </button>
                                       </div>
                                   </div>
                               </EditForm>
                           }
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <FooterComponent />
   }
   ```

Think one issue is that the images are requested very late in my code and produce the flickering...

But how could handle this in a better way? Or maybe another point could be some issue.

Hope you got my point.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pre-rendering (rendering twice) is the reason for flickering. There is a user in github --> https://github.com/Andrzej-W . Just look for issues he has posted, and comments he has made. I recall that he was talking about the problems you are facing now, and asking the Blazor team for new features that can do what you want. You can learn much from this, and may find good solutions...

Comment: My eyes hurt looking at that cascading nested statement.. this is a definite code smell suggesting that this isn't the best approach.

While this approach will work it looks a bit redundant. All these statements are using the `AppState` object - why not just cascade that value, and any component lower down can use the AppState? 

Since this is a globally used state I'd probably recommend using Dependency Injection rather than Cascading parameters in this instance.

Comment: Yes had before Dependency Injection, but changes aren't handled directly and I have to use the whole Event Triggering thing for this to call StateHasChanged event.
I thought when I Cascade AppState all the Components will raise "change" if just one single value is changed - that was the reason to overtake some more Cascading values... but I'm sure there is a better way :-/

Comment: @enet, good point, but I can't see all issues of Andrzey-W in github - how can I search them? Also global search don't give me a way to show issues issued by him... thx....

Comment: search result is empty: https://ibb.co/9p2j7d4

Comment: Start with this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/5464

Comment: Tried in different browsers and issues are really very different for different browser, you should narrow the issue to some smaller reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [`MemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to prevent flickering caused by using `RenderMode.ServerPrerendered`. The issue is discussed [in this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/15266).

The problem with filckering can be avoided by caching the resultset between prerendering and rendering phase on server. Hopefully they fix it somehow in the next release.

> On server-side blazor it is simpler and better to use the in memory
>   cache for that.
>
> - It avoids rountripping the state.
> - It can be combined with a react/redux approach where you simply pass an id for the store and put the store in a memory cache with the
>     id, which is then used to retrieve the store when the app reconnects
>     and to produce an identical render to the one it was prerendered.
>
> As an example below is a modified WeatherService that shows that it
>   causes no flickering.
>
> ```
>     public WeatherForecastService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
>     {
>         MemoryCache = memoryCache;
>     }
>
>     public IMemoryCache MemoryCache { get; }
>
>     public Task<WeatherForecast[]> GetForecastAsync(DateTime startDate)
>     {
>         return MemoryCache.GetOrCreateAsync(startDate, async e =>
>          {
>              e.SetOptions(new MemoryCacheEntryOptions { AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30) });
>              var rng = new Random();
>              await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
>              return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
>              {
>                  Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
>                  TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
>                  Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
>              }).ToArray();
>          });
>     }
>
>     private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
>     {
>         "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
>     };
> ```

The line `await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));` is there just for demonstration purposes, it is certainly not necessary to wait 10 seconds.

Comment: I see, you have probably a different problem, perhaps I should delete the post...